# Can I use python cv2 to generate Chome supported video?

Tags: python, opencv

I have tried MP4V, XVID, DIVX. However, no one can be played directly in Chrome HTML5 Video. Could you give me some examples for FOURCC and file extension combination?

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('out.mp4', fourcc, fps, (w, h))
for img in frames:
    out.write(img)
out.release()
```

Comment: Have you tried `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264')` ?

Comment: "Cannot find encoder". I think it is not shipped with default cv2 package. Some posts mentioned openh264, which is another story.

Comment: What do you mean by "not shipped with default cv2 package" ? What device are you working on?

Comment: FYI. [Here](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/100) . Maybe I should install opencv-contrib. The platform is CentOS 7 x64.